# Unity Android 64 Bit - Not Compliant Error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 64-bit

Running into an issue around a native-Android Unity integration release into the Play Store. I extract it as a project out of Unity and migrate it as a Library in our native app.

When attempting to upload an .AAB into the Play Store, the following error occurs:

```
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [10406]
```

I've already checked the following:

- First, I followed the steps in the official guide: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit
- Unity version: 2019.4.9f1, Android player settings I've selected both ARMv7 and ARM64. No x86 option in this version of Unity. Scripting backend listed as IL2CPP
- In the build.gradle file, I have listed: ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' } as we want to support both 32-bit and 64-bit
- I've used the APK Analyzer tool inside of Android Studio to analyze both the APK and AAB versions of the app. There are the same 10 '.so' files listed in both the lib/armeabi-v7a and lib/arm64-v8a folders.
- Next I used the apktool in combination with the 'file' command to extract the contents of both an APK and AAB version of the app, and double check that the '.so' files inside the arm64-v8a folder are, in fact, 64 bit architecture
- I tested that if I directly install the APK version using the following command on a 64bit device, it was successful:

  ```
  % adb install --abi arm64-v8a app.apk
  Performing Streamed Install
  Success
  ```

I am officially out of ideas and I did contact the Play Store for assistance but they haven't responded in 2 days so I'm getting antsy.

Does anyone have ideas as to what I may have missed?

EDIT:
Forgot to mention, this is also inside the app and unityLibrary build.gradle files:

```
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip '*/armeabi-v7a/*.so'
        doNotStrip '*/arm64-v8a/*.so'
    }
```

Here's a repo containing my simplified gradle files, if it helps:
https://github.com/azdragon2/unityandroid-stackoverflow-question

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stemmed from the usage of '.bc' files contained within a Unity library I was using. These bc files are always interpreted as 32-bit. You'll have to upgrade whichever library you're using that contains these files.

You can determine if you have the same issue by running the following command on your APK or AAB file:

```
zipinfo -1 app.apk | grep \.bc$
```